# Access object properties from typescript

Tags: typescript

Having a *.d.ts file with the following definition:

```
class StateManager {
    states(key:string): Phaser.State;
```

Can be accessed in two ways:

```
myStateManager.states[key]
myStateManager.states(key)
```

But only the first will actually work due to the JS definition of states:

```
this.states = {};
```

**Is there a way to force the correct notation in typescript?**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an index signature here instead?

```
class StateManager {
    states: { [key: string]: Phaser.State };
}
var x = new StateManager();
var p: Phaser.State = x.states['hello']; // OK
var e = x.states('hello'); // Error
```